# Matching on postal code and city name - very slow in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, sql-like

I am trying to update address fields in mytable with data from othertable.
If I match on postal codes and search for city names from othertable in mytable, it works reasonably fast. But as I don't have postal codes in all cases, I also want to look for names only in a 2nd query. This takes hours (>12h). Any ideas what I can do to speed up the query? Please note that indexing did not help. Index scans in (2) weren't faster.

Code for matching on postal code + name (1)

```
update mytable t1 set
admin1 = t.admin1,
admin2 = t.admin2,
admin3 = t.admin3,
postal_code = t.postal_code,
lat = t.lat,
lng = t.lng from (
select * from othertable) t
where t.postal_code = t1.postal_code and     t1.country = t.country
and upper(t1.address) like '%' || t.admin1 || '%' --looks whether city name from othertable shows up in address in t1
and admin1 is null;
```

Code for matching on name only (2)

```
update mytable t1 set
admin1 = t.admin1,
admin2 = t.admin2,
admin3 = t.admin3,
postal_code = t.postal_code,
lat = t.lat,
lng = t.lng from (
select * from othertable) t
where t1.country = t.country
and upper(t1.address) like '%' || t.admin1 || '%' --looks whether city name from othertable shows up in address in t1
and admin1 is null;
```

Query plan 1:

```
"Update on mytable t1           (cost=19084169.53..19205622.16 rows=13781     width=1918)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=19084169.53..19205622.16 rows=13781 width=1918)"
"        Merge Cond: (((t1.postal_code)::text = (othertable.postal_code)::text) AND (t1.country = othertable.country))"
"        Join Filter: (upper((t1.address)::text) ~~ (('%'::text || othertable.admin1) || '%'::text))"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=18332017.34..18347693.77 rows=6270570 width=1661)"
"              Sort Key: t1.postal_code, t1.country"
"              ->  Seq Scan on mytable t1  (cost=0.00..4057214.31 rows=6270570 width=1661)"
"                    Filter: (admin1 IS NULL)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=752152.19..766803.71 rows=2930305 width=92)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=752152.19..759477.95 rows=2930305 width=92)"
"                    Sort Key: othertable.postal_code, othertable.country"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on othertable  (cost=0.00..136924.05 rows=2930305 width=92)"
```

Query plan 2:

```
"Update on mytable t1     (cost=19084169.53..27246633167.33 rows=5464884210 width=1918)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=19084169.53..27246633167.33 rows=5464884210 width=1918)"
"        Merge Cond: (t1.country = othertable.country)"
"        Join Filter: (upper((t1.address)::text) ~~ (('%'::text || othertable.admin1) || '%'::text))"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=18332017.34..18347693.77 rows=6270570 width=1661)"
"              Sort Key: t1.country"
"              ->  Seq Scan on mytable t1  (cost=0.00..4057214.31 rows=6270570 width=1661)"
"                    Filter: (admin1 IS NULL)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=752152.19..766803.71 rows=2930305 width=92)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=752152.19..759477.95 rows=2930305 width=92)"
"                    Sort Key: othertable.country"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on othertable (cost=0.00..136924.05 rows=2930305 width=92)"
```

Comment: Are you expecting to update about 5.4 billion rows in the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second query, you are joining (more or less) on city name, but the `othertable` has several entries per city name, so you are updating `mytable` several times per record, with unpredictable value (which lat-long or other admin2/3  will be the last one to be updated?)

If `othertable` has entries without postal code, use them by adding an extra condition `AND othertable.posalcode is null`

Else, you will want to get a subset of `othertable` that returns one row per `admin1` + `country` value. You would replace `select * from othertable` by the following query. Of course you might want to adjust it to get another lat/long/admin2-3 than the 1st one..

```sql
SELECT admin1, country, first(postal_code) postal_code, first(lat) lat, first(lng) lng, first(admin2) admin2, first(admin3) admin3
FROM  othertable 
GROUP BY admin1,country
```

Worst, the second query overwrite what was updated in the 1st query, so you must ignore these records by adding `and mytable.postalcode is null`

The entire query could be

```sql
UPDATE mytable t1 
SET
    admin1 = t.admin1,
    admin2 = t.admin2,
    admin3 = t.admin3,
    postal_code = t.postal_code,
    lat = t.lat,
    lng = t.lng 
FROM (
    SELECT admin1, country, first(postal_code) postal_code, first(lat) lat, first(lng) lng, first(admin2) admin2, first(admin3) admin3
    FROM  othertable 
    GROUP BY admin1,country) t
WHERE t1.country = t.country
AND upper(t1.address) like '%' || t.admin1 || '%' --looks whether city name from othertable shows up in address in t1
AND admin1 is null
AND mytable.postal_code is null;
```

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand what the problem is. I need to calculate averages of lat/lng, however, not just use the first value per admin1, country